# Identity column separate from composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have a table representing soccer matches:

- Date
- Opponent

I feel {Date,Opponent} is the primary key because in this table there can never be more than one opponent per date. The problem is that when I create foreign key constraints in other tables, I have to include both Date and Opponent columns in the other tables:

Soccer game statistics table:

- Date
- Opponent
- Event (Goal scored, yellow card etc)

Ideally I would like to have:

Soccer matches table:

- ID
- Date
- Opponent

Soccer match statistics table:

- SoccerMatchID
- Event (Goal scored, yellow card etc)

where SoccerMatch.ID is a unique ID (but not the primary key) and {Date,Opponent} is still the primary key.

The problem is SQL Server doesn't seem to let me define ID as being a unique identity whilst {Date,Component} is the primary key. When I go to the properties for ID, the part signalling unique identifying is grayed-out with "No".

(I assume everyone agrees I should try to achieve the above as it's a better design?)

Comment: I just want a unique value ID per match? I usually use identity column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most people don't use the graphical designer to do this, as it's the graphical designer that's preventing it, not SQL Server. Try running DDL in a query window:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX yt_id ON dbo.YourTable(ID);
GO
```

Now you can reference this column in other tables no problem:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeOtherTable
(
  MatchID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.YourTable(ID)
);
```

That said, I find the column name `ID` completely useless. If it's a `MatchID`, why not call it `MatchID` everywhere it appears in the schema? Yes it's redundant in the PK table but IMHO consistency throughout the model is more important.

For that matter, why is your table called `SoccerMatch`? Do you have other kinds of matches? I would think it would be `Matches` with a unique ID = `MatchID`. That way if you later have different types of matches you don't have to create a new table for each sport - just add a `type` column of some sort. If you only ever have soccer, then `SoccerMatch` is kind of redundant, no?

Also I would suggest that the key and unique index be the other way around. If you're not planning to use the multi-column key for external reference then it is more intuitive, at least to me, to make the PK the thing you *do* reference in other tables. So I would say:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Matches
(
  MatchID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  EventDate DATE, -- Date is also a terrible name and it's reserved
  Opponent <? data type ?> / FK reference?
);

ALTER TABLE dbo.Matches ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Matches
  PRIMARY KEY (MatchID);

ALTER TABLE dbo.Matches ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Date_Opponent
  UNIQUE (EventDate, Opponent);
```

Comment: I did call it SoccerMatchID in the statistics table :) I only called it ID in the PK table

Comment: Why not call it SoccerMatchID in the PK table too? That's what it is. ID may be intuitive to you when you're looking at the table designer but when you have it aliased in a query it's a pain in the behind to try and figure out which generic `ID` is which...

Comment: (will do- referring to above). I notice that unique constraint is not done by default when creating an identifier field. Why is this? I am worried about creating a unique index for this identifier field when I havent done for the others. Why does the GUI not create the unique index for identifiers?

Comment: Because the GUI is terrible. Stop using it to design tables.

Comment: Ah ok- so you are saying use the MatchID as the primary key and just ensure a unique constraint on the two columns! So how do I know when to create a candidate key with two columns vs just using a unique constraint?

Comment: Can you tell me what you think is the difference between a "candidate key" and a unique constraint?

Comment: "...never be more than one opponent per date..." suggests the natural composite primary key. However, there are several reasons for using surrogate keys: the unexpected often happens in real life, and the "impossible" sometimes happens, and joining on a single int column is likely more efficient than on multiple columns of various types. One disadvantage I can think of in using the MatchID as PK is that you will most likely end up with a clustered index on an autoincrement-style column where the clustering is not useful in practice.

Comment: @LordPeter if you look at the other elements in the model, I suspect the statistics table will have a LOT of rows for any given match. So would you suggest that instead you store the team, date and opponent for every row in the stats table? That seems pretty wasteful to me. Also you know that the IDENTITY column doesn't have to be clustered, even if it is the PK, right? You can control this depending on your requirements, instead of just "most likely ending up with" something you don't want...

Comment: @AaronBertrand. I was attempting to say "it depends" to OP's question of whether to use multi-column natural key vs single column surrogate key. (At least that's the way I read it!) In this case I agree that propagating multiple columns may indeed be an unnecessary overhead. Clustering on a composite index isn't ideal either because entries in the non-clustered indexes will contain the clustering key as well.